# How to do a React Native count down with animated images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native, react-animated

I am trying to create a react native animation with some images as a count down like this:

```
3 --> ease out down duration 1 second each case
2 --> ease out down
1 --> ease out down
```

I found a way to do this with react animatable, but the results don't convince me, and if there is a better way to do it please let me know.

I think everytime I run into a new render of the element start counting down I say to react animatable to make an iteration of 3 ease out down for each number changing the image number, this is not a natural way of solving the problem I have.

For the moment is not using redux, may be later I will add it.
The properties of the state: time, current time to begin are not being used yet.

All that I need is the effect that a count down is happening with the images I show, in a well defined animation.

I think is almost getting there, but surely there is a better way to face to this problem, any suggestion is well received, even though it is as a guide. I also tried with react-native-animate-number but no luck...

Thanks in advance

```
import React from 'react';
import util from '../utils.js';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainOption: {
  },
  container: {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
const timeLapse = [
              <Image source={require('../images/1.png')} key={util.uniqueId()}/>,
              <Image source={require('../images/2.png')} key={util.uniqueId()}/>,
              <Image source={require('../images/3.png')} key={util.uniqueId()}/>
];

export default class StartingGameCountDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: props.time,
      currentTimeToBegin: props.currentTimeToBegin,
      imagePosition: 0
    };
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const nextImage = this.state.imagePosition + 1;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      letters: nextProps.time,
      currentTimeToBegin: nextProps.currentTimeToBegin,
      imagePosition: nextImage
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animatable.View
               ref='countDown'
               duration={1000}
               delay={0}
               iterationCount={3}
               animation="fadeOutDown"
               style={styles.mainOption}>
          {timeLapse[this.state.imagePosition]}
        </Animatable.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after taking a look into the documentation I found out that may be using sequence and timing could be an option:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  Easing,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

let counter = 0;
const util = {
  uniqueId: () => {
    return counter++;
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainOption: {
  },
  container: {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    top: -100,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
const timeLapse = [
  require('../images/1.png'),
  require('../images/2.png'),
  require('../images/3.png')
];

export default class StartingGameCountDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: props.time,
      countDown: new Animated.Value(0),
      currentTimeToBegin: props.currentTimeToBegin,
      quantity: 3,
      sizes: [],
      duration: props.duration,
      animatedValues: [new Animated.Value(0), new Animated.Value(0), new Animated.Value(0)]
    };
  }
  animations() {
    let result = [];
    state = this.state;
    for(let i = 0; i < state.quantity; i++) {
      //Start
      result.push(Animated.timing(
            state.countDown,
            {
              toValue: 0,
              duration: 0
            }
          )
      );
      let parallel = [];
      //Animate
      for(let j = 0; j < state.quantity; j++) {
        parallel.push(
          Animated.timing(
              state.animatedValues[j],
              {
                easing: Easing.bezier(.07,.42,.85,.5),
                toValue: i === j ? 1 : 0,
                duration: i === j ? state.duration : 0
              }
            )
        );
      }
      //Stop
      parallel.push(Animated.timing(
            state.countDown,
            {
              easing: Easing.bezier(.07,.42,.85,.5),
              toValue: 1,
              duration: state.duration
            }
          )
      );

      result = [...result, Animated.parallel(parallel)];
    }
    return result;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.sequence(this.animations()).start();
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    //I don't to run lifecycle in any case by mistake here
    return false;
  }
  createImagesAnimated() {
    let transitionY = this.state.countDown.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, this.props.transition.y]
    });
    let result = [];
    //What to be Animated
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.quantity; i++) {
      let image = this.state.animatedValues[i].interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1, 0]
      });
      result.push(
          <Animated.Image
              key={util.uniqueId()}
              source={timeLapse[i]}
              style={{
                //How to animate it
                  position: 'absolute',
                  opacity: image,
                  transform: [{
                    translateY: transitionY
                  }]
              }}
          />
      );
    }
    return result;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.createImagesAnimated()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This would be the implementation of the component:

```
    <CountDownComponent
      transition={{y:200}}
      duration={5000}
    />
```

This solves my problem I hope to find in another moment a better solution in the future.

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/jotaoncode/CountDown